# Write a query to give top 10 customers for EACH DAY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have customer_table having columns cust_id, first_name and last_name columns , cust_order table with cust_id, order_id, order_date and amount columns.how to  Write a query to give top 10 customers for EACH DAY

```
;WITH TOP10 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (
        PARTITION BY [order_date] 
        ORDER BY [order_date]
    ) AS RowNo 
    FROM [customer_orders]
)
SELECT * FROM TOP10 WHERE RowNo <= 10
```

The above code is what I tried but I am unable to get the desired out as i need top 10 orders for **EACH DAY**

Comment: What defines a top customer?  Top by what?  Lastest orders?  Amount?  Does `order_date` contain a time?

Comment: I'm thinking that something representing the order amount is needed in the `order by`.

Comment: What is actually the outcome of your query? And why is it not what you want. Allso as a sanity check: does your input contain multiple days?

Comment: Yes input has multiple days where in the output is be top 10 in each day.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH TOP10 AS (
    SELECT C.cust_id, C.first_name, O.order_date,O.amount, ROW_NUMBER() 
    over (
        PARTITION BY O.Order_date 
        order by O.Amount desc
    ) AS RowNo 
    FROM [dbo].[customer_table] C  JOIN [dbo].[customer_orders] O on C.Cust_id=O.Cust_id
)
SELECT * FROM TOP10 WHERE RowNo <= 10
```

It worked